# Use Javascript and fixed url's to navigate between menu pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to use fixed url's and Javascript to switch between menu pages, by having a static `index.php` and a Javascript function that loads html files into a `div` in the index file. An example of what i want is; when the the url is feks `www.example.com/` Javascript loads by deafult `home.html` into `index.php` like this: `$( "#page_include" ).load( "sections/home.html" );`, and so on for `www.example.com/photos/`, and the other menu items. Are there any tutorials for this? Or is it a bad way of doing it? I'm open for other solutions!

Comment: I got that part figured out, but i don't know how to do it with the URL. Like when i loade `www.example.com/pictures/` in the browser it automaticly loads the `pictures.html` into the div

Comment: I see.  Could you not in javascript use `window.location` and a mapping object. 
`var urlToSections = { "/pictures/" : "sections/pictures.html" }; $('#page_include').load(urlToSections[window.location.pathname])`

Comment: it doesnt work, it just prints out an error that the page doesnt exist..